# iPad: UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile performance problems

Tags: iphone, performance, uiimage

I need to display a 20 x 15 grid of images on an iPad. Each image is 50px x 50 px.

I am using `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"name" ofType:@"png"]]` to do this but am running into performance issues. The application lags heavily. There are 14 different types of images, all 50x50 in png format.

Is there a method I could use to increase the performance?

**Update:** I tried using the solution found at the following link; this helped some, but did not completely solve the problem. Hopefully, it helps others. http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/

Comment: Does using `imageNamed:` change the performance at all?

Comment: Are you drawing these images in a drawRect?  Or displaying them inside image views or CALayers?

Comment: The objects themselves are of type UIVIew 50px x 50 px. They contain an image (same size px) (Squares of varying textures)

Comment: How are they being drawn? Try using UIImageView,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

imageNamed will cache the image so will be faster on the second use etc. If that doesn't help then you can pre-load the images if memory is not too badly affected and then just swap them out of an NSArray or NSMutableArray for example.

Comment: I load up an array of images, then when I init an object of type UIView, I set the views image to the appropriate index in the array that holds the image.